# How to fix OpenGLES glDrawElements

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

When attempting to draw a cube loaded from an .obj file all triangles share a single point. Additionally not all of the triangles seem to be rendering.

I've noticed that changing the vertex count for glDrawElements allows the other triangles to draw, but am uncertain as to why the number of points would be greater than the number of indices being used.

I've checked that the file (seems to be) loaded correctly with the debugger as:
In the ModelObject class 'vCoords' contains:

```
{
 1.0,  1.0,  1.0, 
-1.0, -1.0,  1.0, 
 1.0, -1.0,  1.0, 
-1.0,  1.0,  1.0, 
-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 
 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 
 1.0,  1.0, -1.0, 
-1.0,  1.0, -1.0
}
```

and each MaterialGroup has 6 indices that are offset by -1 from the obj file.
(.obj indices start at 1 instead of 0)

Each MaterialGroup's indices are on a separate line (also pulled from debugger during draw calls)

```
{ 3, 6, 7, 3, 0, 6 }  //yellow
{ 0, 5, 6, 0, 2, 5 }  //blue
{ 5, 7, 6, 5, 4, 7 }  //purple
{ 2, 4, 5, 2, 1, 4 }  //red
{ 1, 7, 4, 1, 3, 7 }  //white
{ 0, 1, 2, 0, 3, 1 }  //light green
```

In the ModelObject class:

```
public void draw(float[] mvpm, GLProgram program){
        int mvpmH  = program.getUniformLocation("mvpm");

        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(posH);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(
                posH,
                COORDS_PER_VERTEX,
                GLES20.GL_FLOAT,
                    false,
                COORDS_PER_VERTEX*Float.BYTES,
                vCoords);
        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mvpmH, 1, false, mvpm,0 );
        GLErrorLogger.check();
        for(MaterialGroup materialGroup : groups){

            materialGroup.draw(program);
        }

        GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(posH);
        GLErrorLogger.check();
}
```

In the MaterialGroup class:

```
public void draw(GLProgram program){
        GLErrorLogger.check();
        int colorH = program.getUniformAttribLocation("vColor");
        GLErrorLogger.check();
        GLES20.glUniform4fv(colorH, 1, material.diffuse, 0);
        GLErrorLogger.check();

        //GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, points);
        GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, iv.limit(), 
                 GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, iv);

        GLErrorLogger.check();
}
```

iv is the index buffer
vCoords is a buffer containing all the vertices

The source full can be located at: https://github.com/TheIncgi/GLES_GAME_fixed/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/theincgi/gles_game_fixed/geometry/ModelLoader2.java

Current result:
[Current render issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oX4U.gif)

Goal:
[What the cube should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3u2x.png)

Edit 1: Fixed formatting issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 3rd parameter of [`glDrawElements`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDrawElements.xhtml) specifies the type of the values in the list of indices.

The buffer (`iv`) is an `int` buffer, where each element has 4 bytes.

> ```
> IntBuffer   iv, it, in;
> ```

But the OpenGL enumerator constant `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT` indicated that the buffer is a buffer of `short` values, where the size of each value is 2 bytes:

> ```
> GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, iv.limit(), GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, iv);
> ```

If the OpenGL ES version supports `GL_UNSIGNED_INT`, then it is sufficient to change `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT` by `GL_UNSIGNED_INT` to solve the issue:

```java
GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, iv.limit(), GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, iv);
```

If `GL_UNSIGNED_INT` is not uspported, then a `ShortBuffer` has to be crated instead of `IntBuffer`:

```
ShortBuffer iv;

GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, iv.limit(), GLS20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, iv);
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Had a feeling it was something simple I overlooked. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Spec though says that in ES 2.0 it only accepts `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` and `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT`. I have tested it though, and on some devices that works with `GL_UNSIGNED_INT`, but you probably shouldn't rely on that too much.

Comment: @Reaper Thank's. I was sloppy and didn't consider the OpenGL ES version.